# Changing image dimensions in the Controller with ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have been trying to use the ng-file-upload module for sometime now and have met with considerable success.
My current requirement is to store 2 versions of the uploaded image, one the original and the other a thumbnail. My current code can store the thumbnail or the original but I can't find a way to do them both from the html. Is there any way to do this from the controller?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-4 columns">
        <button class="button" type="file" ng-model="myActionsCtrl.image" ngf-select="myActionsCtrl.browseImage($file, $invalidFiles)" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB">Browse</button>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-4 columns">
        <button class="button" ng-click="myActionsCtrl.uploadImage()">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
module.exports = function ($scope, Upload, AuthService) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.user = AuthService.user

    vm.uploadImage = function () {
        if (vm.file) {
            vm.file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: '/uploads/gallery',
                method: 'POST',
                file: vm.file
            });

            vm.file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    vm.file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) { }
                // $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                vm.file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                    evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    }

    vm.browseImage = function (file, errFiles) {
        $scope.file = file;
        vm.file = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do it on the server side (at the `'/uploads/gallery'` endpoint)

Comment: @AlonEitan But this would mean that my server needs to bear the load. Not a big issue right now though. Is there any module handy for this?

Comment: If you want to make a thumbnail version of the image and then upload it you can use `Upload.resize(options).then(function(resizedFile) {...})` service and then upload the resizedFile.